# Using SoftwareSerial.h in .cpp file

Tags: softwareserial, compilation-errors, cpp

I am trying to modularize the different components in my arduino build by using objects, but am having trouble with the one controlling a wireless transceiver, which uses `SoftwareSerial.h`

I believe I am (generally) setting up the use of these objects correctly because I have other objects that build correctly in other files.

I think my issue is somehow part of `SoftwareSerial.h`, but I am not knowledgeable enough to get in and diagnose it... I think my core issue is that `SoftwareSerial` is not being brought in properly.

**Transciever.cpp**

```cpp
/*
   This code controls the HC-12 transciever
*/
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

enum class TransReadStatus {
  RELAY_OFF,
  RELAY_ON,
  NO_DATA
};

class TranscieverHandler {
  public:
    TranscieverHandler(
      int txPinIn,
      int rxPinIn,
      int setPinIn,
      int baudRateIn
    ): txPin(txPinIn),
      rxPin(rxPinIn),
      setPin(setPinIn),
      baudRate(baudRateIn)
    {
      SoftwareSerial hc12(txPin, rxPin);
    }

    void init() {
      hc12.begin(baudRate);
      pinMode(setPin, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(setPin, HIGH);  // HC-12 normal, transparent mode
    }


    TransReadStatus checkForSignal() {
      while (hc12.available()) {             // If HC-12 has data
        incomingByte = hc12.read();          // Store each icoming byte from HC-12
        readBuffer += char(incomingByte);    // Add each byte to ReadBuffer string variable
      }
      delay(100);

      if (onBytes.equals(readBuffer)) {
        readBuffer = "";
        return TransReadStatus::RELAY_ON;
      } else if (offBytes.equals(readBuffer)) {
        readBuffer = "";
        return TransReadStatus::RELAY_OFF;
      }
      readBuffer = "";
      return TransReadStatus::NO_DATA;
    }

    TransReadStatus getLastRecievedStatus() {
      TransReadStatus newStatus = checkForSignal();

      if (newStatus == TransReadStatus::NO_DATA) {
        return lastStatus;
      }
      lastStatus = newStatus;
      return lastStatus;
    }

  protected:
    const int txPin;// = 10;
    const int rxPin;// = 11;
    const int setPin;// = 12;
    const int baudRate;// 9600
    /*
       Constants for signals
    */
    const String setOnBytes = String("SET RELAY ON");
    const String setOffBytes = String("SET RELAY OFF");
    const String onBytes = String("STATUS: RELAY IS ON");
    const String offBytes = String("STATUS: RELAY IS OFF");

    SoftwareSerial hc12;

    byte incomingByte;
    String readBuffer = "";
    TransReadStatus lastStatus = TransReadStatus::NO_DATA;
    unsigned long lastSendOnSignal = millis();


};
```

**Output from failed compilation:**

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware -tools /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/tools-builder -tools /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -built-in-libraries /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/libraries -libraries /home/greg/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10809 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_227628 -warnings=default -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_459309 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware -tools /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/tools-builder -tools /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -built-in-libraries /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/libraries -libraries /home/greg/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10809 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_227628 -warnings=default -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_459309 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr
Detecting libraries used...
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/SwitchController.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/SwitchController.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
Using cached library dependencies for file: /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Buttons.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/LEDs.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Switches.cpp
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp -o /dev/null
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.cpp -o /dev/null
Generating function prototypes...
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/SwitchController.ino.cpp -o /tmp/arduino_build_227628/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /tmp/arduino_build_227628/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
Compiling sketch...
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Buttons.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Switches.cpp.o
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/SwitchController.ino.cpp -o /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/SwitchController.ino.cpp.o
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard -I/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp -o /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/LEDs.cpp.o
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp: In constructor 'TranscieverHandler::TranscieverHandler(int, int, int, int)':
Transciever.cpp:23:26: error: no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()'
       baudRate(baudRateIn)
                          ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:92:3: note: candidate: SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(uint8_t, uint8_t, bool)
   SoftwareSerial(uint8_t receivePin, uint8_t transmitPin, bool inverse_logic = false);

   ^
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:92:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:50:7: note: candidate: constexpr SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(const SoftwareSerial&)
 class SoftwareSerial : public Stream

       ^
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:50:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp: In member function 'void TranscieverHandler::init()':
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:29:26: warning: passing 'const SoftwareSerial' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       hc12.begin(baudRate);
                          ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:94:8: note:   in call to 'void SoftwareSerial::begin(long int)'
   void begin(long speed);

        ^
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp: In member function 'TransReadStatus TranscieverHandler::checkForSignal()':
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:36:29: warning: passing 'const SoftwareSerial' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       while (hc12.available()) {             // If HC-12 has data
                             ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:104:15: note:   in call to 'virtual int SoftwareSerial::available()'
   virtual int available();

               ^
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:37:34: warning: passing 'const SoftwareSerial' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         incomingByte = hc12.read();          // Store each icoming byte from HC-12
                                  ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:103:15: note:   in call to 'virtual int SoftwareSerial::read()'
   virtual int read();

               ^
In file included from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:0:
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp: In constructor 'TranscieverHandler::TranscieverHandler(int, int, int, int)':
Transciever.cpp:23:26: error: no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()'
       baudRate(baudRateIn)
                          ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0,
                 from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:92:3: note: candidate: SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(uint8_t, uint8_t, bool)
   SoftwareSerial(uint8_t receivePin, uint8_t transmitPin, bool inverse_logic = false);

   ^
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:92:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:50:7: note: candidate: constexpr SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(const SoftwareSerial&)
 class SoftwareSerial : public Stream

       ^
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:50:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:0:
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp: In member function 'void TranscieverHandler::init()':
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:29:26: warning: passing 'const SoftwareSerial' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       hc12.begin(baudRate);
                          ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0,
                 from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:94:8: note:   in call to 'void SoftwareSerial::begin(long int)'
   void begin(long speed);

        ^
In file included from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:0:
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp: In member function 'TransReadStatus TranscieverHandler::checkForSignal()':
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:36:29: warning: passing 'const SoftwareSerial' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       while (hc12.available()) {             // If HC-12 has data
                             ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0,
                 from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:104:15: note:   in call to 'virtual int SoftwareSerial::available()'
   virtual int available();

               ^
In file included from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:0:
/tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:37:34: warning: passing 'const SoftwareSerial' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         incomingByte = hc12.read();          // Store each icoming byte from HC-12
                                  ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_227628/sketch/Transciever.cpp:5:0,
                 from /home/greg/GitRepos/WirelessSwitch/SwitchController/SwitchController.ino:32:
/home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h:103:15: note:   in call to 'virtual int SoftwareSerial::read()'
   virtual int read();

               ^
Using library SoftwareSerial at version 1.0 in folder: /home/greg/other/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial 
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()'
```

Comment: `: hc12(txPin, rxPin),..`

Comment: @Juraj I figured I was doing something simple wrong. If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member initialization is intended for objects construction. For ints you can do an assignment in the constructors body

```
TranscieverHandler(int txPinIn, int rxPinIn, int setPinIn, int baudRateIn)
    : hc12(txPin, rxPin) {
  txPin = txPinIn;
  rxPin = rxPinIn;
  setPin = setPinIn;
  baudRate = baudRateIn;
}
```

Comment: Good to know, it had been a while since I last touched real c++ code

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-5a-constructor-member-initializer-lists/